# How to use a Checkbox to change text in Flutter/Dart using an array/list (troubles with onChanged/setState)

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, setstate

Thanks in advance, I am fairly new to this and have followed a few tutorials and read countless posts here.

I am working on a personal project and have struck a dead end.

I wish to change the text within a text widget by use of a checkbox, in essence turning it on and off.
Unfortunately what at first seemed simple has driven me insane for the last week or so, I apologize if this has been answered but I can't find the help I need, I have found things similar but nothing has worked so far.

I'm trying to change my int value with an onchanged and set staff function with a list/array and an int value, I effectively want to set the value from 0 to 1 and then back again.

```
var textChange = [" could be ", " have become "];
int t = 0;
```

with;

```
onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  boxChecked = value!;
                  if (boxChecked) {
                    t = 1;
                  } else if (!boxChecked){
                    t = 0;
                  }
                  }
                );
              },
```

I have made sure I am extending a Stateful Widget tried setting up different functions and methods to pass through, I have tried using a material button instead of a checkbox but still hit the same issue.
I have tried a few different ways to write my onset function including something as simple as [t++ or t = (d + 1) % textChange.length;] but these would ultimately end in error once the int = >2, but I couldn't even get the value of my int to change.
If I changed it manually and run the program, it works. however, I can't seem to get my onchanged and set state code to affect my array or int.
I even had my original array as List, changed it to var in hopes it would make it mutable.

I hope I said that right, I am clearly missing something but I've looked at so much I'm just lost.

Below is the code I have used with the fat trimmed from the rest of my project. I'm using android studios with the latest updates.

Thanks for your help and time.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'alternate text code',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'alternate text'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);


  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child:
              Text(
                'I am having trouble getting some code to work, I have tried '
                'a lot of things but can't work it out.'
                'I would like the check box to change the line of text below,
              ),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child:
                ChangeText(),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child:
              Text(
                'you' + textChange[t] + 'a App Developer.',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool boxChecked = false;

class ChangeText extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChangeText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChangeText> createState() => _ChangeText();
}

var textChange = [" could be ", " have become "];
int t = 0;

class _ChangeText extends State<ChangeText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child:
      Container(
            child: CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('learn Flutter', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
              value: boxChecked,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  boxChecked = value!;
                  if (boxChecked) {
                    t = 1;
                  } else if (!boxChecked){
                    t = 0;
                  }
                  }
                );
              },
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `ChangeText` widget, you are calling `setState` mean it will only change the UI within `ChangeText` widget. However, Text reflect need to happened on `MyHomePage`. You can use global key to change the parent state or just use callback method like

```dart
class ChangeText extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callBack;
  const ChangeText({
    Key? key,
    required this.callBack,
  }) : super(key: key);

........
    onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            boxChecked = value!;
            if (boxChecked) {
              t = 1;
            } else if (!boxChecked) {
              t = 0;
            }
          });
          widget.callBack();
        },
```

and use like

```dart
              child: ChangeText(
                callBack: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
```

**Full Widgets**

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'alternate text code',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'alternate text'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child: Text(
                'I am having trouble getting some code to work, i have tried '
                'a lot of things but cant work it out.'
                'I would like the check box to change the line of text below',
              ),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child: ChangeText(
                callBack: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
            ),
            Divider(),
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.2,
              child: Text(
                'you' + textChange[t] + 'a App Developer.',
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

bool boxChecked = false;

class ChangeText extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function callBack;
  const ChangeText({
    Key? key,
    required this.callBack,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChangeText> createState() => _ChangeText();
}

var textChange = [" could be ", " have become "];
int t = 0;

class _ChangeText extends State<ChangeText> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        // Expanded(
        //   child:

        Container(
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        title: const Text(
          'learn Flutter',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
        ),
        value: boxChecked,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            boxChecked = value!;
            if (boxChecked) {
              t = 1;
            } else if (!boxChecked) {
              t = 0;
            }
          });
          widget.callBack();
        },
      ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, the code you provided fixed my issue. being new to this i still dont quite understand how it worked, im not sure what a global key is (more learning). 
Atleast iknow what my issue was and now what to read up on.
Simply put: 
The required.this added to the ChangeText class allows for the setstate to be passed to the homepage. is this correct?

Comment: Also, in the future, you may always choose state management for these cases.